# What is the linear transformation that sends every matrix $A$ onto $PA$, where $P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, real-numbers

Let $X$ be the space of all real $2\times2$ matrices and let $T$ be the linear transformation that sends every matrix $A$ onto $PA,$ where $P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$ Find the matrix $T$ with respect to the basis consisting of $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$

I don't think I understand what is being asked here. At a glance, it seems like we're looking for a matrix $T$ such that $TA = PA,$ so my instinct is to say $T = P,$ but that feels like it's missing what the question is asking. I'm also stuck on the word *onto,* because that implies something different that equality which was my first thought.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: The real $2\times2$ matrices form a $4$-dimensional vector space, so you'll need a $4\times4$ matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you're using $T$ for both the transformation and the matrix, which is causing some of the confusion here.  Let's let $T$ be the transformation and $M$ the matrix.  The space $X$ is $4$-dimensional, and
you're given the basis to use, let's call these four matrices $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4$.  So $M$ will be a $4 \times 4$ matrix.
The entry $m_{ij}$ in row $i$, column $j$, will be the coefficient of $E_j$ when writing $T(E_i) = P E_i$ in this basis.
For example, with $i=1$ we take
$$T(E_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr} \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 1 & 0\cr} = E_1 + E_3$$ so the first row of $M$ is
$(1, 0, 1, 0)$.